# Caching of HTML pages

Tags: html, caching

I have included meta tags for Cache-control - no cache and Pragma no cache and Expires in my html page. But still i find the html pages in Temporary Internet Files folder on my system with expires timestamp.

If i make another request to server after the timestamp expiration value, the page my browser is going to show is a new page or a cached page from the folder on my system.

How to test, whether the page is a cached page or a new page from Server?

Answer (score 0):

Go to a page which shows the time (or some other dynamic value), then compare the time it shows on your first page load to the value it shows you on the second page load.